# Adding two seperate firebase projects for a single app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I want to implement e-commerce apps on IOS and Android. I can divide the apps into two parts less secured, more secured. I can say more secure is a case of accepting payments in the app.So for this purpose, I want to have separate login systems for entering into the app and making payments.I am using Firebase Authentication and in that Password Authentication.So at the start of the project if we want to use Firebase(for Authentication, Database)we need to add google-services.json for Android App and GoogleService-Info.plist for IOS App. But now I want to add two firebase projects for a single app. How is it possible?

Comment: Check this lanswer:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632243/multiple-firebase-projects-in-one-app

Comment: Have a look at the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_ios_application

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't have two src folders like the example.I only have one and I want to use two different firestore projects in the same app.This is the use case user wants to buy a product, up to that point the app needs to use 1 Database when the user wants to pay then the user is redirected to payments methods from then onwards app uses another database(for security reasons)

Answer (score 1):

### Use multiple firebase projects in single application

Simply can access multiple projects through FirebaseApp configure.

#### Configuration

```
        let secondaryOptions = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "your google app id",
                                               gcmSenderID: "your gcm id")
        secondaryOptions.apiKey = "your api key"
        secondaryOptions.projectID = "your projectid"
        
        secondaryOptions.bundleID = "your bundle id"
        secondaryOptions.databaseURL = "https://yourproject.firebaseio.com"
        secondaryOptions.storageBucket = "yourproject.appspot.com"
        secondaryOptions.androidClientID = "yourproject.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        secondaryOptions.deepLinkURLScheme = "myapp://"
        secondaryOptions.storageBucket = "yourprojectId.appspot.com"
        secondaryOptions.appGroupID = nil
        FirebaseApp.configure(name: "secondary", options: secondaryOptions)
```

#### Usage

```
        guard let secondary = FirebaseApp.app(name: "secondary")
         else { assert(false, "Could not retrieve secondary app") }
         
        let secondaryDb = Database.database(app: secondary)
```

Answer (score -3):

in your firebase. open up a project and click on 'add another project'.

and then select app for IOS or Android. You are done.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, @user9238383 I am not asking about how to use single Firebase Project by multiple apps.Its exact opposite to the question I have asked.