# Multiple Firebase Projects in one app with different persistence setup

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to setup 2 Firebase in 1 App, but with difference persistence.

One is enable, and the second is disable.

Please inform me how to set it up.

I take code from link below,

[Multiple Firebase projects in one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632243/multiple-firebase-projects-in-one-app)

but it didn't explain,

how to setup persistence for the second Firebase.

I want to enable persistence for 1st Firebase.

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

And disable persistence for 2nd Firebase.

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);`

As we see, that getInstance is static method,

how do we know that,

the returned FirebaseDatabase instance,

will belong to 1st or 2nd Firebase.

```
private void initSecondFirebaseAcct()
{
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApplicationId("<your application id>")
        .setApiKey("<your api key>")
        .setDatabaseUrl("<your DB url that ends in 'firebaseio.com/' ")
        .build();

    try
    {
       FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "<database tag>");
    }catch (Exception e){
       Log.d("Firebase error", "App already exists");
    }

    mMySecondApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance("<database tag>");
    mSecondDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(mMySecondApp).getReference();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to make sure you are referencing the first or second Firebase app is to provide the specific `FirebaseApp` instance as a parameter to:

`FireDatabase.getInstance(<app instance here>).setPersistenceEnabled()`.

If you use `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` you will receive the default instance, the first database app. So just provide the second instance as a parameter and you'll be good to go.